# $A \in M(n,\mathbb R)$ has all its eigenvalues real , then is it true that all the eigenvalues of $A^2-A$ are also real?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

Let $A \in M(n,\mathbb R)$ has all its eigenvalues real , then is it true that all the eigenvalues of $A^2-A$ are real ?

[ Note that if $k$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ then $k^2-k$ is an eigenvalue of $A^2-A$ , but to address my  question it is not enough as it does not  describe "all the eigenvalues "  of $A^2-A$ ]

Please help . Thanks in advance

Comment: don't you get all eigenvalues from that ? , you have $k^2-k$ for all eigenvalues of $k$ giving all eigenvalues of the new matrix

Comment: https://math.uc.edu/~halpern/Matrix.methods/Homatrixmethods/Spectralmappingthm.pdf

Comment: @avz2611 : I don't think so , doesn't it only show that $\{k^2-k:k$ is an eigenvalue of $A\}$ $\subseteq \{ \lambda :\lambda $ is an eigenvalue of $A^2-A\}$ ?

Comment: Strictly speaking, the statement that *"$A\in M_n(\mathbb R)$ has all its eigenvalues real"* is a tautology (if the field is $\mathbb F$, by definition all eigenvalues --- if exist --- must be a scalar in $\mathbb F$), but usually, what it really means is that *"$A\in M_n(\mathbb R)$ has $n$ real eigenvalues"* or *"all eigenvalues of $A\in M_n(\color{red}{\mathbb C})$ are real"*.

Comment: @user1551 : Yes , by eigenvalue I also do mean to include those in the algebraic closure $\mathbb C$ of $\mathbb R$ , thank you :)

Comment: @happymath : Thank you , the document  came to a lot of help . I think you should put it ( just the link if not more ) to an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the insistence of the OP here is a nice link which tells about spectral mapping property https://math.uc.edu/~halpern/Matrix.methods/Homatrixmethods/Spectralmappingthm.pdf

Answer (score 1):

$A$ is similar to a Jordan matrix $J$, and so $A^2-A$ is similar to $J^2-J$.  But $J$ is upper triangular with real entries, so is $J^2-J$, its eigenvalues are its diagonal elements which are real, and these are also the eigenvalues of $A^2-A$.